# Easiest (most forgiving?) way to learn category theory?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, self-learning

I'm not a maths student, but I've read a bit on category theory and I'd love to learn about it.

Is there any book that's simple enough for a busy student to pick up and learn the fundamentals? What are the prerequisites? Thanks!

Comment: There are many questions on this site (and SO, I think) addressing this issue and similar ones.

Comment: Just start putting "-morphism" at the end of every word you say. You'll be a category theorist in no time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great book is [Conceptual Mathematics](http://www.amazon.ca/Conceptual-Mathematics-First-Introduction-Categories/dp/052171916X). It starts from the very very basics and moves to incredibly complex category theory concepts.

Furthermore, it requires almost no prerequisite knowledge.

Comment: I second this recommendation.  Fantastic book.

Comment: @Downvoter, may I know how to improve this answer further?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a more algebraic point of view, George Bergman at UC Berkeley has a good introductory text you can find here https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/245/index.html

with a free pdf copy to download. It does, admittedly, assume some basic undergraduate abstract algebra knowledge but if you're asking about category theory then you might have that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a programmer, my [blogbook on category theory](http://bartoszmilewski.com/2014/10/28/category-theory-for-programmers-the-preface/) might fit your requirements.